# How can we run e2e tests from different repos

Tags: cypress, github-actions

We have mainly three repos in our project.Currently the automation test runs automatically when a pull request created against the `e2e-automation` repo.
How can I run the same automation tests from `front-end-main` & `api-gateway-main` repos while a pull request is being created using github actions work flow ? Can someone please advise ?

//Project Github Repos:

```
e2e-automation repo // cypress automation tests

front-end-main repo  // react js front end 

api-gateway-main repo // api services
```

// .github\workflows\main.yml

```
name: Cypress Automation Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  push:
    branches: [main]
env:
  CYPRESS_CARGO_BOOKING_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_CARGO_BOOKING_PASSWORD }}
  CYPRESS_CARGO_SIGNUP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_CARGO_SIGNUP_PASSWORD }}
jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          # perform the installation
          runTests: false
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: install
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        # we re-install the dependencies
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          # perform the installation
          runTests: false
      - name: Run e2e automation regression tests
        run: npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@Regression+-@Failing",ENV="staging" --browser chrome
      - name: Upload Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: cypress/videos
```

This is just a `draft` try out as per advised in the below answer:

This is the existing automation repo
`e2e-automation repo`, which run cypress automation tests, which has the `main.yml` file with below contents only

```
name: Cypress Automation Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: my-github-account/cypress-test-action
```

So in the below front end repo, i need to create a new `action.yml` file with contents copied from the original `mail.yml` file:

`front-end-main repo`  // react js front end

```
name: Cypress Automation Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  push:
    branches: [main]
env:
  CYPRESS_CARGO_BOOKING_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_CARGO_BOOKING_PASSWORD }}
  CYPRESS_CARGO_SIGNUP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_CARGO_SIGNUP_PASSWORD }}
jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          # perform the installation
          runTests: false
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    needs: install
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        # we re-install the dependencies
      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          # perform the installation
          runTests: false
      - name: Run e2e automation regression tests
        run: npm run cy:run -- --env grepTags="@Regression+-@Failing",ENV="staging" --browser chrome
      - name: Upload Results
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        if: always()
        with:
          name: cypress-videos
          path: cypress/videos
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the step `uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2`.

This links to the Cypress repo at [cypress-io/github-action](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#explicit-version).

> **Explicit version**
>
> ```js
> - name: Cypress run
>   uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
> ```
>
> When using cypress-io/github-action@v5 from your workflow file, you automatically will be using the latest tagged version from this repository.

Ignore for the moment you are calling a quite old version of Cypress' action.

**Create your common action**

You can do a similar thing on your domain - set up a repo on your Github account just for the common action, say `my-github-account/cypress-test-action`.

In that repo create `action.yml` file and put inside the code you currently have in `main.yml` (shown in the question).

The only thing that you should change from above `main.yml` is to remove the `on:` section since you will only ever call it directly from the other repos, never on `pull_request` or `push` in the *new* repo.

**Calling common action**

Then in each of the three repos listed above, the `main.yml` will have just one job and step that calls `cypress-test-action`.

These repos will have the `on:` section as per old `main.yml`, and only one job and one step to kick-off the common action.

// main.yml

```js
name: Cypress Automation Tests
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    steps:
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: my-github-account/cypress-test-action
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will create a draft and attach to the question. So could you please check as well. ?

Comment: I have added in the question, could you please check if that is the correct way.

Comment: That may be ok, but it's different to what I had in mind. I was thinking that you would have a brand new repo called something like `cypress-test-action` (but it can be called anything you like). Then all 3 existing repos have the modified `main.yml` with single step  `uses: my-github-account/cypress-test-action` - and you need to change `my-github-account` part to whatever your account is called (e.g `soccerway-account`)

Comment: The other difference is the new repo has `action.yml` in the root folder and the existing 3 repos have `main.yml` in `.github/workflows` folder.

Comment: And in the new `action.yml` you should remove the `on:` section because it will error when you `push` or `pull-request` on that repo, since there is nothing to test in the new repo.